# Android profiler 0 memory leak but native memory bitmap increasing

Tags: android, memory-leaks, imageview, android-bitmap

Hi im using android profiler to check for memory leak. Apparently there is none, however i notice the native memory keeps increasing per image attached.

Majority are from Bitmap i supposed?

Would like to know if ImageView with src = "@mipmap/etc.png", contribute to native memory keeps increasing?

[image of my android profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbo2I.png)